# Can F# update immutable bindings in a class (create a new object with the specified bindings changed?)

Tags: .net, f#, ocaml, f#-3.0

Is there a way for F# to update immutable bindings inside a class?  Or, more specifically, is there a way to copy a class definition and change a single immutable entry?  For example, in OCaml, we can write code such as

```ocaml
let foo = object
  val fuz = 1
  method get_fuz = fuz
  method inc_fuz = {< fuz = fuz+1 >}
end

let _ = foo#get_fuz
let foo = foo#inc_fuz
let _ = foo#get_fuz
```

This program yields

```
val foo : < get_fuz : int; inc_fuz : 'a > as 'a = <obj>
- : int = 1
val foo : < get_fuz : int; inc_fuz : 'a > as 'a = <obj>
- : int = 2
```

Basically, the syntax `{< >}` allows us to, in some sense, update immutable properties by making a new object with all of the same entries except the specified ones changed.  Is there an analogous operation in F#?

Comment: There's  the _copy and update record expression_ which I guess would be an analogy for records see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christian is right in this case you would usually just do:

### using a record/function

```
type foo = { fuz : int }

let inc_fuz f = { f with fuz = f.fuz + 1 }
```

#### test:

```
> inc_fuz { fuz = 5 }
val it : foo = {fuz = 6;}
```

### using a record with member

of if it has to be a member:

```
type foo = 
    { fuz : int } 
    member f.inc_fuz = { f with fuz = f.fuz + 1 }
```

#### test:

```
> let test = { fuz = 5 };;
val test : foo = {fuz = 5;}

> test.inc_fuz;;
val it : foo = {fuz = 6;}
```